# Centering a td-displayed div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table, created with divs, not with the `<table>`. I did it quite well I think, but I want to "`colspan`" two divs. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN8de/1/) for you.

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='tr'>
   <div class='td'>Vorname:</div>
   <div class='td'><input type='text' name='vorname' placeholder='Max' required='required'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr_placeholder'>
   Hauptwohnsitz:
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
   <div class='td'>Stra&szlig;e &amp; Hausnummer:</div>
   <div class='td'><input type='text' name='strasse0' placeholder='Musterstra&szlig;e 15' required='required'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The `tr_placeholder` should have a "colspan=2" but since colspan is a table html attribute I can't use it in css. So is there a possibility to manipulate my css that it works? This is my actual class:

```
.tr_placeholder{
display:table-row;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;
width:400px;
}
```

The solution should be **Javascript free please**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish can be done much easier by abandoning the idea of a "table" and just using regular HTML. Try this:

```
<style>
    label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
<form>
    <h2>Section heading here</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Vorname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="vorname" placeholder="Max" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <h2>Hauptwohnsitz</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stra&szlig;e &amp; Hausnummer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="strasse0" placeholder="Musterstra&szlig;e 15" required="required"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate an extra cell to each row and set `.tr_placeholder` in absolute position on top of it :
http://jsfiddle.net/ZN8de/2/

```
.table {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;

}
.tr:before {
    display:table-cell;
    content:'';
    width:100px;
}
.td {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.tr_placeholder {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
        border-top:1px dotted #000000;
}
.tr_placeholder:before {
    display:none;
}
```